# Fastest way to find prime factors after sieve

Tags: performance, time-complexity, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, factorization

I have stored all the prime numbers upto a range in a vector `primes` after `sieve`. Now I want to find all the prime factors of `n` in short time.

My code:

```
    i=0
    while(primes[i]<=n)
    {
        if(n%primes[i]==0)
        {
           cout<<primes[i]<<endl;
        }
        while(n%primes[i]==0)
            n/=primes[i];
        i++;
    }
```

But this is not efficient, please suggest any modifications possible.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be more efficient because I'm eliminating the other loop in your code. I tested this in C# except I tested it with hard coded number.

I think this is the code you want to see. Hopefully it is more efficient. I wrote it in C# and didn't have a list of prime numbers so I hard coded on (Or enough of it for my example)

Code I think will work based off your code

```
i = 0
while(n > 1)
{
    if(n % primes[i] == 0)
    {
       cout<<primes[i]<<endl;
       n /= primes[i];
    }
    else
        i++;
}
```

Code I wrote in C# that I think mimicked your code or at least what I think you were doing.

```
        int n = 1806046;
        int[] primes;
        primes = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 439, 601, 733, 941, 1151 };
        int i = 0;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            if (n % primes[i] == 0)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(primes[i]);
                n /= primes[i];
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
```

This is the code I tested and based it off of in C#. Which Worked great and iterated all numbers instead of just primes.

```
        int x = 1806046;
        int i = 2;

        while (x > 1)
        {
            if (x % i++ == 0)
            {
                x /= --i;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Actually it is taking almost the same time.

Comment: Oh man, how fast does this need to be exactly? Also are you coding in C?

Comment: I am using c++, in one file there are around 10^7 numbers and the constraints of number are from 1 <= n <= 10^6. Within 1.5s approx(don't consider printing time)

Comment: Have you tried using a conditional operator? `(n % primes[i] == 0)?(n /= primes[i]):(i++)`  I think I remember something about it using like a line or two less in machine code while operating. I don't know if this will boost any performance, but it's worth a try at this point.

Comment: Here are a couple algorithms that will more than likely be faster if you want to give them a go. They are written in python, but the conversion shouldn't be too painful from Python to C++. Best of luck and I hope these help!  https://comeoncodeon.wordpress.com/2010/09/18/pollard-rho-brent-integer-factorization/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91423/discussion-between-cold-coder-and-timmy).

Answer (score 1):

You are checking all the primes up to `n`.  You don't need to do that.  Once you have removed all the factors up to, and including `sqrt(n)` then either the remaining unfactorised part is itself prime or it is 1.

You can exit the outer loop when `n == 1` since there are no more prime factors to be found.  Think of a number like 16, with lots of small prime factors.

You are entering the inner loop every time through the outer loop.  You don't need to do that; you only need the inner loop when your `if` is true.

Once inside the `if` you can save repeating a modulus calculation by changing the `while` loop to a `do` loop.

```
i = 0;

// Find prime factors up to square root.
limit = sqrt(n);
while ((primes[i] <= limit) && (n > 1))
{
    if (n % primes[i] == 0)
    {
       cout << primes[i] << endl;
       do 
       {
           n /= primes[i];
       } while (n % primes[i] == 0);
    }
    i++;
}

// Find possible factor above square root.
if (n > 1) 
{
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

I have not tested the code so better to test it yourself.

Comment: IMO this is a fast loop structure.  One big improvement is to recalculate `limit` after the while but still inside the if statement.  `n` (the unfactored part) has been reduced so we don't have to look as far.

Comment: I considered that.  It really depends on the speed of the square root calculation.  Probably best to try both ways and see which is faster on a given machine.  I also got the impression that cold_coder wanted a reasonably simple answer so I decided not to include that tweak. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

The key to solve this problem is understand there can be only one prime >= square_root(N) .

So, you can just iterate through the prime list upto square_root(N) . You can do something like this code below :

[Factor generation](http://pastebin.com/sxxLb1FZ)